# Android and firebase issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one question, every time i want to insert data, it is replacing the old data either from another email as well,  and when i go and change that line  ref.child("User01").setValue(user); user01 to user02 then it is generating another user, so can u plz tell me how i resolve that issue......... , so that from one email i can create one user and when i login from other user, it will automatically create another user.

```
  public void btnInsert(View view) {
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            getValues();
            ref.child("User01").setValue(user);
            Toast.makeText(EditableProfileActivity.this,"Data Inserted Successfully......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void btnLogout(View view) {
    firebaseAuth.signOut();
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll typically store the user data in the database under each user's UID (which is guaranteed to be unique for each user).

If your `user` variable points to a [Firebase Authentication `User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) then this can be done with:

```
ref.child(user.getUid()).setValue(user);
```